# Cordova / PhoneGap InAppBrowser toolbar stretching... WHY?

Tags: cordova-plugins, inappbrowser

[image]

Can anyone explain why this is happening?

I have fiddled with it and nothing I do works

Comment: Was a solution ever found for this?

Answer (score 0):

try updating in-app-browser to latest (1.4.0).

Comment: did this help?  strugling with the same thing

Comment: @pushplaybang had it on this project -- https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.psstapp.psstapp